# React Checkbox Does Not Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, redux, react-redux

I want to update an array each time a checkbox is toggled to true. With this current code, if I click on a checkbox it will log that it's false. Even though I have just updated the state. Does setState just take some time, like an API call? That doesn't make sense to me.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Person extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      boxIsChecked: false
    };

    this.checkboxToggle = this.checkboxToggle.bind(this);
  }

  checkboxToggle() {
    // state is updated first
    this.setState({ boxIsChecked: !this.state.boxIsChecked });
    console.log("boxIsChecked: " + this.state.boxIsChecked);
    if (this.state.boxIsChecked === false) {
      console.log("box is false. should do nothing.");
    }
    else if (this.state.boxIsChecked === true) {
      console.log("box is true. should be added.");
      this.props.setForDelete(this.props.person._id);
    }

  }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="person" checked={this.state.boxIsChecked} onClick={this.checkboxToggle} />
            {this.props.person.name} ({this.props.person.age})
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Person;
```

I have tried onChange instead of onClick. I feel like I'm already following advice I've read about for the basic component formulation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478945/react-js-cant-change-checkbox-state) and [here](http://www.automationfuel.com/reactjs-checkboxes/). Is the fact I'm using Redux for other values affecting anything? Is there a way to just read what the checkbox is, instead of trying to control it? (The checkbox itself works fine and the DOM updates wether it's checked or not correctly.)

Comment: Your code snippet is not using Redux at all. It is using regular React state.

Comment: Yeah, I was just checking if there might be some side effects that could be causing some problems. I am using some Redux actions in the component, as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

setState() is indeed not reflected right away:

[Read here in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React
>   that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the
>   updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user
>   interface in response to event handlers and server responses.
>
> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
>   update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
>   delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
>   does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.
>
> setState() will always lead to a re-render unless
>   shouldComponentUpdate() returns false. If mutable objects are being
>   used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in
>   shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state
>   differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

[and here some experiments](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)

So it might be better to catch the event and check it, and not depend on the `this.setState()`
Something like that:

```
handleChange: function (event)  {
   //you code
    if (event.target.checked) {
      console.log("box is true. should be added.");
      this.props.setForDelete(this.props.person._id);
    }

  }
```

and

```
    render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="person" checked={this.state.boxIsChecked} 
                   onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
                {this.props.person.name} ({this.props.person.age})
              </div>
            );
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This might be an elementary question, but are there any resources you could link me to that talk about capturing or using an event, like checking or unchecking? I would prefer to just observe whether the checkbox is checked or not without having to keep track of that value on state.

Comment: @GabrielKunkel  I edited the code snippet. This is how I do that. Please try. But you still need to use `setState` to reflect the changes in the checkbox, or to remove `checked` attribute completely.

Comment: @GabrielKunkel this link might be helpful, also you can have bunch of key words you can you use in further research: http://help.dottoro.com/ljihlcqe.php

Comment: Nice answer with nice explanation. Thank you...!

Answer (score 43):

I know that this thread is answered but i also have a solution for this, you see the checkbox didn't update with the provided value of setState, i don't know the exact reason for this problem but here is a solution.

```
<input
  key={Math.random()}
  type="checkbox"
  name="insurance"
  defaultChecked={data.insurance}
 />
```

by giving the key value of random the checkbox gets re-rendered and the value of the checkbox is updated, this worked for me. Also i am using hooks, but it should work for class based implementation to.

reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/8unyps/am_i_doing_stupid_or_is_this_a_bug_checkbox_not/

Comment: This with an onChange is clearly the best solution. +1

Comment: This answer help me a lot.

Comment: using 'defaultChecked' instead of 'checked' together with random key solved it, thx! Only need this solution when getting value from props. With values from useState always works.

Comment: This a great answer! It elegantly skirts around the truly hacked nature of javascript nonsense! Still can't believe we all have to put up with this in 2023.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access the updated value of `state` just after calling setState().

If you want to do stuff with updated value of state, you can do like this. i.e inside `setState()` callback function

```
     checkboxToggle() {
        // state is updated first
        this.setState({ boxIsChecked: !this.state.boxIsChecked },()=>{

        console.log("boxIsChecked: " + this.state.boxIsChecked);
        if (this.state.boxIsChecked === false) {
          console.log("box is false. should do nothing.");
        }
        else if (this.state.boxIsChecked === true) {
          console.log("box is true. should be added.");
          this.props.setForDelete(this.props.person._id);
        }


});
```

Comment: Well, that makes sense. I don't know why it didn't cross my mind that setState might take a callback. Can we use promises do you know?

Comment: why do you want to use promise and what do you want to achieve using promise? SetState callback will do what you need. correct?

Comment: I was just curious. I'm more inclined to use promises. ;P

Comment: React's setState() doesn't return a promise. Stick with the callback's.

Comment: @GabrielKunkel You can [wrap it in a promise](https://gist.github.com/doug65536/6b14b729174e80067373c4e08d8e9342),

Answer (score 3):

To expand no newbies answer; what worked for me:

- remove preventDefault() from onChange Event-Listener but this didn't feel right for me since I want only react to update the value. And it might not apply in all cases like OPs.
- include the checked value in the key like `key={"agree_legal_checkbox" + legalcheckboxValue} checked={legalcheckboxValue}`

I got both these solutions from newbies answer but having a math.random key just felt wrong. Using the value for checked causes the key only to change when when the checked value changes as well.

(not enough reputation to simply post this as a comment, but still wanted to share)

Answer (score 2):

React solution:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" ref={checkboxRef} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

JS:

```
const checkboxRef = useRef("");
  const [checkbox, setCheckbox] = useState(false);
  const handleChange = () => {
    setCheckbox(checkboxRef.current.checked);
  };
```

Now your true/false value is stored in the checkbox variable

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here trying to figure out why my checkbox, rendered using the [HTM](https://github.com/developit/htm) tagged template library, wasn't working.

```js
return html`
  ...
  <input type="checkbox" checked=${state.active ? "checked" : null} />
  ...
`;
```

It turns out I was just trying too hard with that ternary operator. This works fine:

```js
return html`
  ...
  <input type="checkbox" checked=${state.active} />
  ...
`;
```